# OpenEDX development procedure

Tags: openedx

I'm currently trying to make my own platform based on OpenEDX and I'm working with devstack to do that. Am i right that I need to install fullstack on my server and make them share a git repository for update or is that not a right way to do that?

P.S. Sorry if it's not a right place for the question but I couldn't find a better one.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to do Native installation on the server. And then share the git repository. [Here](https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OpenOPS/pages/146440579/Native+Open+edX+Ubuntu+16.04+64+bit+Installation) is the link if you want to deploy all the services on the single instance, But if you want to setup a multi tier architecture then you need to deploy all the services separately using edx-ansible.

Comment: Any idea about how to do this via edx-ansible? Do you have any sample code?

Comment: You can change the variables and git repo in the roles which will automatically deploy your code rather then default open edx code.

Comment: Do you have any repository with some examples on this?

Comment: Nope. Don't have any repository.